# Debug error, abort() has been called in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to perform error checking on my initializer value for date, so that a day or month outside the acceptable range will stop the program from debbuging, but I'm getting a debug error even for the acceptable range. I don't know where the error is from, so i posted the code.

```
// ConsoleApplication56.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<stdexcept>
#include<array>

using namespace std;

class Date
{
public:
    explicit Date(int mo, int da, int ye)
    {
        setDate( mo, da, ye);
    }
    void setDate(int &m, int &d, int &y)
    {

            setMonth(m);
            setDay(d);
            setYear(y);

    }
    void setMonth(int &m)
    {
        if (month>0 && month <13)
        {
        month = m;
        }else
            throw invalid_argument("month must be 1-12");
    }
    unsigned int getMonth()const
    {
        return month;
    }
    void setDay(int &d)
    {
        if(day>0 && day<32)
        {
        day = d;
        }else
            throw invalid_argument("day must be 0-31");
    }
    unsigned int getDay()const
    {
        return day;
    }
    void setYear(int &y)
    {
        year = y;

    }
    unsigned int getYear()const
    {
        return year;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout<< month <<'/' << day << '/' << year;
    }
    void nextDay()
    {
        int numberOfDaysToAdd = 1;
    array <int,12> daysInAMonth = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

    cout << "the date before is: " << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << endl;

    day += numberOfDaysToAdd;

    while (day > daysInAMonth [month - 1 ] )
    {
        day-= daysInAMonth [month - 1 ];
        month++;

        if (month > 12){
          month = 1;
          year++;
        }

    }

    cout << "the day after is: " <<  month << "/" << day << "/" << year << endl;

    }

private:
    unsigned int month;
    unsigned int day;
    unsigned int year;
};


int main()
{
    char response = 'y';
    Date date(12, 3, 2013 );

    cout<<"The date is :";
    date.print();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"do you wish to check the next date(y/n)? :";
    cin >> response;
    cout<<endl;

    while(response == 'y')
    {
    date.nextDay();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"do you wish to check the next date(y/n)? : ";
    cin >> response;
    cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please cut down your example, you are more likely to receive meaningful answers that way as well as being reasonable with your readers time and effort they need to put into helping you. I suggest you remove code until the problem goes away to arrive at a minimal testcase.

Comment: what error? which line?

Answer (score 2):

You should check the `m` and `d` values not the `month` and `day` member variables.

```
void setMonth(int &m)
{
  if (month>0 && month <13)
```

should be

```
void setMonth(int &m)
{
  if (m>0 && m <13)
```